# Unable to install core20, unable to install any snap applications

Tags: 20.04, snap

```
sudo snap refresh
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "core20" (1891) (cannot verify snap "core20", no matching signatures found)
```

Ubuntu 20.04

Tried:

- Reinstalling snapd

Is this a problem?

---

Removed core20 and all snap packages,  however I can now no longer install any apps, due to the above error when trying to run

```
sudo snap install core20
```

This is a fresh install.